# Using fork() to determine line count of all command line arguments

Tags: c, fork, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use fork with command line arguments so that each child process determines whether the argument is a valid filename or not. If it is, I want to count the amount of lines in the file and return 0 if even, or 1 if odd. I want the parent process to be able to use these returned numbers to output whether the number of lines in all of the files together is odd or even.

I have tried to write a bit of code (below), but I'm clearly very new to C and have no idea how to go about this whatsoever. I'm just hoping someone might be able to give me a few tips or point me in the right direction to get myself started.

Thanks heaps, I appreciate any help!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  pid_t child_pid = fork();

  if (child_pid == 0) 
  {
    exit(-1)
  }

  else if (pid > 0) 
  {
    valid = access (pid, R_OK);
    if (valid == 0) 
    {
      /** count number of lines in file 
          return 0 if even, 1 if odd
       */
    }
    else 
    {
      exit(-1)
    }
  }

  else
  {
    return 1;
  }
  /* use child returned values to determine whether odd or even amount of lines in all files */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (child_pid == 0)  { exit(-1); }` will simply terminate every child just created. Read `man fork`. Also this code won't compile at all...

Comment: What you want to do is not very clear... You want to count the number of lines in a file passed as argument? Why using `fork` is that an homework assigment?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm aware the code won't compile as is, I was just putting down anything I'd got to and was hoping for tips

Comment: Learning the language first before starting with libraries and multiprocessing is always a good idea.

Comment: @Brittany I don't think it is a good approach. Start with minimal compiling program. Then add stuff to it, periodically testing.

Comment: @purplepsycho online question I'm trying to answer, I want to use fork for each command line argument to create a child process that will handle that argument. The child will determine whether the argument is a valid filename, and if it is will count the number of lines and return 0 for even or 1 for odd. The parents process will cause all child processes to execute in parallel and will use their return to determine whether the overall number of lines is even or odd

Comment: what is the child process to return when the passed command line argument is NOT a valid file?  What about files which are not organized in lines?

Comment: the syntax for `access()` `int access(const char *pathname, int mode);`  Note that the first parameter is NOT a PID but rather a pathname.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reference for the `fork` function [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html). Reading it, you'll learn that it returns `0` to the child process and the child's PID to the parent process. So, you need something like this for `n` processes:

```
int   i;
pid_t pid;

for(i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
  pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0) break;
}

if(pid == 0)
{
  // Do child's job
}
else
{
  // Do parent's job
}
```

Where the parent's job certainly include waiting for the children to terminate computing and displaying whatever you need.

[Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/access.html) is a reference to the `access` function as it seems to be also another problem.